# Numeric bug on access db

Tags: sql, ms-access, numbers, field

[image: fields type]

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE number >= '" + numberFrom + "' 
AND number <= '" + numberTo + "' 
ORDER BY number DESC
```

(number is "text" field)

`numberFrom` and `numberTo` are a range from "1080" to "2000",
but if i have one record with number "108" the `SELECT` find this record (even if we know that is out of the range).

How i can fix this?

Comment: Column data type? (You're probably doing character string comparisons, not numerical.)

Comment: i can choose between this field: text, small number, integer, byte, single, double, currency, date, memo. How can select a numerical string??

Comment: `WHERE number >= Int(" & numberFrom & ")"` etc Note that the concatenator in MS Access is generally & not +, + is a different story, but a useful one. You also have cint, clng, and val.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing **alphabetic comparison** where for that matter '9' > '19'.
If you want to compare numbers you should use numbers.

Comment: what do you mean with "you should use numbers"?? i need a number fiel but in access i can't find one!

Comment: @Pelandro - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30ad644f-946c-442e-8bd2-be067361987c#bm2g

Comment: @Pelandro - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Data-types-for-Access-apps-33e10f90-5b06-4e56-ab0e-b0930f4c2367

Comment: @Pelandro, **Double**